# Is it possible to load a word document or text files in Couchbase?

Tags: couchbase, nosql

I am new to NoSQL and also to Couchbase.
I have created the bucket by using,

> curl- Administrator:admin -d name=test -d ramQuotaMB=100 -d coutctype=none -d replicaNumber=0 -d proxyport=11216 http://localhost:8091/pools/defaults/buckets

and now I want to upload text files as in like resumes to this bucket.
How can I do it?
Is it possible to upload the word document in Couchbase?
Where do we design the schema for these documents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couchbase is a *schema-less* nosql database, you do not have to specify the structure of the data before you store it. This means you can mix what you store in a single bucket and change the content of documents as you please. It is possible to store word documents, or anything else for that matter, in Couchbase by storing them as *binary documents*. Couchbase allows you to store any arbitrary data as long as it conforms to the normal [document constraints](http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/admin/Misc/limits.html), such as the 20MB size limit. You should bear in mind that binary documents have limited functionality compared to JSON documents, for example you cannot use the view engine with binary documents.

The supported way to interact with Couchbase is via one of the [client SDK's](http://docs.couchbase.com/developer/dev-guide-3.0/intro.html), these will give you the best flexibility and performance. Pick your preferred language from the list of client libraries (located just below the Couchbase server download links) and then head over to the [developer documentation](http://docs.couchbase.com/developer/dev-guide-3.0/intro.html) for a general overview on how to get started and then further information for each of the clients.

Comment: thanks Adam Taylor for your response.  with this it is clear that when we will upload any text format file in couchbase it will convert it to the binary format so on which i wont be able to do search operation. Do i have to convert these text document to json file before putting it in to couchbase?

Comment: I want to upoad the resume in couchbase and then provide the search interface for it. so what can be the procedure?

Comment: Correct, to use views and indexes you will need to store documents as JSON. All of the client SDK's allow for generating JSON documents manually and creating JSON documents from language native data structures.

Comment: thanks Adam Taylor, for your response, how can configure Java SDK for couchbase, i have downloaded the sdk and now i am not getting how to use it to create the json file with these sdk

Comment: The [Java SDK documentation](http://docs.couchbase.com/developer/java-2.1/java-intro.html) describes the setup, configuration and usage far better than I can. I'd recommend having a look through that. :)